# vscode Python extension other than pylance

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

My question is: Is there any extension for vscode which supports code navigation in Python other than PyLance?

A bit of context:
I'm running Python on vscode, and there are some features that I need that are not available on PyLance, I have contacted the PyLance team and they rejected my proposal for adding these features and suggesting moving to other extension.
With that said, it seems like PyLance is the only extension which supports code navigation in vscode Python. I couldn't any up-to-date documentation on Jedi. or any other extension that does that.

Comment: "_I have contacted the PyLance team and they rejected my proposal for adding these features and suggesting moving to other extension_" link please